# JSON: obtener dos propiedades distintas de dos objetos en una conversión con stringify

Tags: json

Teniendo el siguiente objeto JSON:

```
var employees = {
      "staff": [{
        "firstName": "Tony",
        "lastName": "deAraujo",
        "age": 99
      }, {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "age": 33
      }, {
        "firstName": "Mary",
        "lastName": "Adams",
        "age": 29
      }],
      "management": [{
        "firstName": "Judy",
        "lastName": "Garland",
        "age": 43
      }]
    };
```

**Quisiera saber si es posible mostrar en una misma conversión con stringify:**

`firstName` y `lastName` de `staff` y `age` de `management`.

Ya que se que se puede hacer por separado asi:

```
 var resultado = JSON.stringify(employees, ["staff", "firstName","lastName"]);

 var resultado2 = JSON.stringify(employees, ["management", "age"]);
```

Trate haciendo lo siguiente:

1)  `var resultado = JSON.stringify(employees, ["staff", "firstName","lastName" ,"management", "age"]);`

Pero me devuelve `firstName` , `lastName` , `age` tanto de `staff`como de  `management`.

```
{"staff":[{"firstName":"Tony","age":99},{"firstName":"John","age":33},{"firstName":"Mary","age":29},{"firstName":"Loren","age":29}],"management":[{"firstName":"Judy","age":43},{"firstName":"Loren","age":29}]}
```

2) `var someString = JSON.stringify(employees, ["staff", "firstName","lastName"],["management", "age"]);`

Pero me devuelve solo `firstName` y `lastName` de `staff`

```
{"staff":[{"firstName":"Tony","lastName":"deAraujo"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Adams"},{"firstName":"Loren","lastName":"Santos"}]}
```

Resultado esperado:

```
{"staff":[{"firstName":"Tony","lastName":"resultado"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"resultado"},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"resultado"},{"firstName":"Loren","lastName":"resultado"}],"management":[{"age":"43","age":"23"}}
```

Supongo que algo asi, creo que me faltan comas y llaves.

Comment: puedes poner el ejemplo de como quieres el json para tu objeto?

Comment: @ArieCwHat dejame intentar armarlo jejeje

Comment: Por qué `[{"age":43,"age":23}]` como resultado esperado en management? De donde sale el 23? Porqué pones en resultado esperado de `staff` la propiedad `age` si más arriba dices que quieres `firstName` y `lastName`?

Comment: Le especifique a ariel que trataria de armarlo, no me fije bien en lo que copie

Comment: De acuerdo, no pasa nada!! =))

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo listo jejejeje, tranquilo tu tambien :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que usar `JSON.stringify` para hacer este proceso de esta manera, es complicarse demasiado.
Recorriendo el array puedes ir escogiendo las claves que formarán parte de tu nuevo JSON. (Primer Ejemplo)

Aunque si lo deseas puedes utilizar el segundo argumento de `JSON.stringify` pero en vez de pasarle un Array, debes pasarle una función. 
En esta función (que recibe la `clave` y el `valor` del objeto que está convirtiendo a `string`) comprobamos la clave y formteamos el contenido de `staff` y `management` para que los objetos dentro de esos Arrays contengan solo las propiedades que queremos (Segundo ejemeplo)

```js
var employees = {"staff":[{"firstName":"Tony","lastName":"deAraujo","age":99},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","age":33},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Adams","age":29}],"management":[{"firstName":"Judy","lastName":"Garland","age":43}]};

let fnParse = (key, array) => 
  key == 'staff' 
    ? array[key].map( ({firstName, lastName}) => ({firstName, lastName}) )
    : array[key].map( ({age}) => ({age}) )

let formatted = 
  Object
  .keys(employees)
  .reduce( (obj, key) => (obj[key] = fnParse(key, employees), obj), {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(formatted));

let formattedStr = JSON.stringify(employees, (key, val)=>{
  if(key == 'staff') 
    return val.map( ({firstName, lastName}) => ({firstName, lastName}) );
  if(key == 'management') 
    return val.map( ({age}) => ({age}) );
  return val;
});
console.log(formattedStr);
```

Para ver el código en ES5 [**Pincha aquí**](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20employees%20%3D%20%7B%22staff%22%3A[%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22Tony%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22deAraujo%22%2C%22age%22%3A99%7D%2C%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22Smith%22%2C%22age%22%3A33%7D%2C%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22Mary%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22Adams%22%2C%22age%22%3A29%7D]%2C%22management%22%3A[%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22Judy%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22Garland%22%2C%22age%22%3A43%7D]%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20fnParse%20%3D%20(key%2C%20array)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20key%20%3D%3D%20'staff'%20%0A%20%3F%20array[key].map(%20(%7BfirstName%2C%20lastName%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7BfirstName%2C%20lastName%7D)%20)%0A%20%3A%20array[key].map(%20(%7Bage%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7Bage%7D)%20)%0A%0Alet%20formatted%20%3D%20%0A%20Object%0A%20.keys(employees)%0A%20.reduce(%20(obj%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20(obj[key]%20%3D%20fnParse(key%2C%20employees)%2C%20obj)%2C%20%7B%7D)%0A%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(formatted))%3B%0A%0Alet%20formattedStr%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(employees%2C%20(key%2C%20val)%3D%3E%7B%0A%20if(key%20%3D%3D%20'staff')%20%0A%20return%20val.map(%20(%7BfirstName%2C%20lastName%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7BfirstName%2C%20lastName%7D)%20)%3B%0A%20if(key%20%3D%3D%20'management')%20%0A%20return%20val.map(%20(%7Bage%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7Bage%7D)%20)%3B%0A%20return%20val%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(formattedStr)%3B)

Comment: Estaba leyendo de las funciones, y trate de meter algo asi: JSON.strigify(employees, function(key,value){}, function(key,value){});

Comment: el segundo ejemplo me parece genial, pero como funciona .map, si pudieras agregarlo seria genial :)

Comment: `Array#map` devuelve un nuevo array a partir del original, para cada elemento dentro del array se ejecuta la función que se le pasa y hará que modifique el elemento contenido en el array. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Comment: sobre (key,val)=>{ es eso obligatorio el => ? pues en mi libro sale (key,val){ o es porque esta contenido dentro del let?

Comment: Es una sintaxis "nueva". Se podría escribir como `function(key, val){}`. He editado la respuesta con un link donde podrás ver el código en la versión ES5 de JS.